# Setup SQL Server data structure that corresponds to PLC data structure

Tags: arrays, sql-server, data-structures, plc

I need to setup a recipe database in Microsoft SQL Server. The recipes are now stored in the PLC. The data structure, in the PLC, is as shown below.

`typRecipe` in PLC (one record/recipe):

- Name         : string
- NumLayers    : int
- MoldType     : string
- MatRoll1Name : string
- MatRoll2Name : string
- LayerLength  : array[1..200]
- LayerOffset  : array[1..200]
- UseRoll1     : array[1..200]
- UseRoll2     : array[1..200]
- Velocity     : array[1..10]
- VelocityZone : array[1..10]

My question is: how can I setup a table in SQL Server that corresponds to the PLC data structure? The record, as a whole, is then transferred to the PLC, through an OPC server. Recipe name is the key index.

Regards,
Agnar

Comment: int is INT, String is NVARCHR(length) and array would be Table Value Parameter

Answer (score 0):

Each of your atomic (ie:  single-valued) properties (Name, NumLayers, MoldType, MatRollNames) should be columns in the Recipe table.

Each of your array columns should be represented by a one-to-many relationship with other tables.  (A Layer table with Length and Offset columns; A Roll table and a Velocity table).